# What is the effect of an std::move()'d variable passed as a copy?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just picked up Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers at my local library. On page 4 of my copy, Meyers writes about the different types of copies: copy via move constructor and copy via copy constructor. The example given was the following code:

```
void someFunc(Foo f); 
Foo bar; 
someFunc(bar); 
someFunc(std::move(bar));
```

My question is how can the function someFunc accept a rvalue reference created by std::move when the argument type is not rvalue reference?

Comment: Can you please [show a concise code example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51314815/edit) what your concerns are about?

Comment: `void f(double); f(1);` I'm passing an `int`, but the function is expecting a `double`. Same thing happening in your sample.

Comment: @Rakete1111 it's nothing like that at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function expects a value - not a reference, so when a reference is passed as an argument, a copy of some object is being made.

When you pass an **lvalue** reference, the argument becomes a copy of the object binded with said reference - it is being *copy constructed*. You have an *object*, a *reference to that object* and a *copy constructed argument that was created based on the said object*.

When you pass an **rvalue** reference, is seems like not a lot of things change. You still have *some object*, some *reference to it* and *another object that is being created based on the original one*, **but** this time, the newly created object is being created via **move constructor**.

What is the difference? For primitive types, none. Moving and copying `int`s, `char`s and such does pretty much the same thing. The differences can be observed when we unit test the function with an object that actually uses move construction in some way. Let's maybe take a look at how `std::string` behaves:

```
void foo(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << " ";
}

int main()
{
    std::string first   = "abc";
    std::string& second = first;
    std::string third   = "ghi";

    foo(first);             // copy the first string and display it
    foo(second);            // copy the first string and display it
    foo(std::move(third));  // move the third string and display it
}
```

Given this example, the comments say very little. We already established that here we copy construct, there we move construct. But what does it actually mean?

Moving an object is not so trivial topic. I encourage you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/7151494) to get some insights on it. Tl;dr-ing, when you **move** an `std::string`, you don't make an whole new copy - you create another object which steals the representation of the original and leaves it in valid, but unspecified state.

Concluding:
Given the first two calls to `foo()`, the parameter being a value and arguments being values **or** references, we are ending up with a simple **copy**. Given the third call, we are providing an **rvalue reference**, thus we enforce a **move construction** (because arguments type is a value, not a reference, so it needs an actual object), which will take the `third` string, create an entirely new one inside `foo`s call stack, steal it's internal pointer, leave `third` in some valid state (you might end up with `third` begin an empty `std::string` with `0` size, but that's **unspecified**) and display the moved string.

Comment: Thanks. The missing piece was constructor being called when you pass an object to a function that takes a non-reference. I figured it would fail because there is not a rvalue reference in parameters, but obviously this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the example code:

```
void someFunc(Foo f); 
Foo bar; 
someFunc(bar); 
someFunc(std::move(bar));
```

The function `someFunc` doesn't even know how the call was made. It always receives the value `f`.

---

What happens at the call site depends on the constructors of `Foo`. There could be a separate move constructor:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo();
   Foo(const Foo&);
   Foo(Foo&&);
};
```

And then the parameters would be handled by the different constructors.

---

But it could also be that Foo only has a copy constructor. Perhaps because moving doesn't improve anything for this class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo();
   Foo(const Foo&);
};
```

Then both calls would end up being identical.

---

It could even be that a (slightly perverse) class forbids moving by deleting the move constructor:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo();
   Foo(const Foo&);
   Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
};
```

Then the second call will fail.

---

So - it depends!